# C++ object construction with garbage, why?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have had the following structure:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    struct Displacement
    {
        bool            isWrapped;
        int             steps;
    };

    int                     initialDuration;
    int                     currentDuration;
    Displacement            displacement1;
    Displacement            displacement2;
};
```

And I was using it like this:

```
MyStruct obj{2, 2};
auto shared = std::make_shared<MyStruct>(obj);
```

The problem was that I needed to duplicate first two arguments as `initialDuration` and `currentDuration` should be the same when a new object is created. Therefore I have created a CTOR:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    struct Displacement
    {
        bool            isWrapped;
        int             steps;
    };

    MyStruct(int duration) 
          : initialDuration(duration)
          , currentDuration(duration)
    {
    }

    int                     initialDuration;
    int                     currentDuration;
    Displacement            displacement1;
    Displacement            displacement2;
};
```

and then used like this:

```
    auto shared = std::make_shared<MyStruct>(2);
```

**The unexpected thing 1 is:** both `Displacement` members of `MyStruct` have been initialized with garbage. For one the `bool` member of `true`, for the other one - `false` and `int`s were some arbitrary numbers.

So though maybe I need to define CTOR for `Displacement` too. Defined like this:

```
    struct Displacement
    {
        Displacement() : isWrapped(false), steps(0) {}

        bool            isWrapped;
        int             steps;
    };
```

**The unexpected thing 2 is:** that somewhere else

```
  MyStruct::Displacement d {false, 0};
```

started to not compile. I don't know [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) or [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) stopped working for a POD struct when I have defined the default CTOR.

Please explain the reasons of those 2 behaviours.

Comment: It would be easier to answer this if you have only one question. With an MCVE.

Comment: @juanchopanza totally agree, only the problem is that I would break all this nice history. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your 1st question

> both Displacement members of MyStruct have been initialized with garbage.
>
> (from comment) There should be a default CTOR for Displacement defined by the compiler which should be called in the CTOR of MyStruct that I have defined, right?

The [implicitly-defined default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) won't do anything here.

> If the implicitly-declared default constructor is not defined as deleted, it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and compiled) by the compiler, and it has exactly the same effect as a user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list. That is, it calls the default constructors of the bases and of the non-static members of this class.

And for `MyStruct obj{2, 2};`, `obj` is an automatic object, so (from standard $8.5/12 Initializers [dcl.init])

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object
>   with automatic or dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an **indeterminate value**, and if
>   no initialization is performed for the object, that object retains an indeterminate value until that value is
>   replaced (5.18). [ Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. —
>   end note ]

You might want to initialize them as

```
MyStruct obj{2, 2, {false, 0}, {false, 0}};
```

For your 2nd question

> I don't know aggregate initialization or list-initialization stopped working for a POD struct when I have defined the default CTOR.

Yes it does, unless you provide another ctor which takes [std::initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as its parameter. See [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

> An aggregate is an object of the type that is one of the following
>
> ```
> array type  
> class type (typically, struct or union), that has  
>     no private or protected non-static data members
>     no user-provided constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11)
>     no base classes
>     no virtual member functions 
>     no default member initializers (since C++11) (until C++14)
> ```

Comment: But why they are initialized with garbage? There should be a default CTOR for `Displacement` defined by the compiler which should be called in the CTOR of `MyStruct` that I have defined, right?

Comment: @Narek The [implicitly-defined default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) won't do anything here. "If the implicitly-declared default constructor is not defined as deleted, it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and compiled) by the compiler, and it has exactly the same effect as a user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list. That is, it calls the default constructors of the bases and of the non-static members of this class. "

Comment: You mean it will not value-initialize built-in, right? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

Comment: @Narek Yes, for automatic or dynamic storage.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a constructor that is called you need to explicitly initialize all members, or they will be uninitialized. Uninitialized members will have *indeterminate* values which is what you perceive as garbage. That's how C++ work when you have constructors.

From [this implicit default constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-defined_default_constructor):

> If the implicitly-declared default constructor is not defined as deleted, it is defined ... by the compiler, and it has exactly the same effect as a user-defined constructor with empty body and empty initializer list. That is, it calls the default constructors of the bases and of the non-static members of this class.

Built-in or aggregate types have no constructor, and so can't be constructed or initialized without an explicit initialization.

Comment: Why, default CTOR will be called for them, right? And default for POD initializes to `false` for `bool` and `0` for `int` right?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You wouldn't *need* to explicitly initialize all the members if they had, say, a user defined default constructor. The issue here is that the members are either aggregates consisting of built-ins, or built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

Your struct is no longer a [POD type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) when you add a default constructor. Among other things, a POD type must have a [trivial default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Trivial_default_constructor).

You need to add a constructor that takes two arguments for your code to start working again. Also note that the default constructor does not 0-initialize members. The reason it worked before with the POD type is that doing aggregate initialization (which only works with POD types) defaults members not explicitly initialized to 0.